# Java swing. How to wait for other Jframes

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt

In a JFrame, when I click on 'login', I pop up another Jframe which is the login window.

How do I make my main Jframe wait for my login Jframe to exit, before doing anything else?

Comment: Can we presume there is a reason you aren't putting the login into a modal dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a modal dialog in stead of a frame, that way you cannot do anything else until it'is closed

see http://mindprod.com/jgloss/modal.html for explanation
and see http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ASimpleModalDialog.htm for code example

If you insist on using a JFrame, you could use a workaround by cover the other frame by a glassframe..  Not too a nice solution, I admit..

Comment: I would advise the same, but nonetheless, could you suggest how could be ANY JFrame made modal? I come from Delphi world, and there one would call myForm.showModal; instead of just myForm.show; Is there any simple way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Not that I know of, but my swing is very rusty, it has been years so don't trust me on this one

Comment: Modality is only available for classes that subclass java.awt.Dialog (like javax.swing.JDialog), classes that subclass just java.awt.Window can't be model.

Comment: @Andreas_D, change your comment into an answer and I would give you an upvote

Comment: note that if you use a JModal, you must call its constructor with "true" in order for it to block the parent from being active until it closes, like new MyClass(this, true)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that a modal dialog would be the best option here, but if I were to answer this question in it's more general form, say:

> How do I make one JFrame wait for another JFrame?

I would say the easiest way to acheive this is by registering and firing event listeners.

- In your "child" frame, register the "main" frame as an event listener.
- In your "main" frame,

  - implement your choice of listener, e.g. `ActionListener`
  - in the method called by the listener, e.g. `actionPerformed`, code the logic that handles what happens upon each of the actions it can respond to in the "child" frame.

One can easily implement this to a ny number of situations, including the login scenario described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JModalFrame](http://jmodalwindow.java.net/) instead of JFrame.

Comment: JModalFrame isn't part of the standard Swing API.